# Allow access only to group, but API to all

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, authorization, intranet

I have an mvc4 intranet website that I am working on that has a web front-end that only a few AD groups will have access to, but I am also using the web API functionality of mvc4 and I need that open to all users, even anonymous ones. I have tried using the Web.config, but that blocks all users who are not in one of the groups.

How would I go about securing the front-end while keeping the API open?

**Update:**

I just thought, I would like to avoid tagging each method with an attribute
like `[Authorize]`

Comment: are you using .NET Membership?

Comment: no, its an intranet app and is using AD (Active Directory)

Comment: you can benefit of [.NET Membership even using AD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx)! It will make your work better and faster!

Comment: I wasn't even looking for that, but thats awesome and I think I can use it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I simply applied a filter that checked the namespace of each controller. Since all my API controllers are in `HSServer.Controllers.Api` and all the web controllers are in `HSServer.Controllers.Web` this code in my `FilterConfig.cs` worked like a charm.

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new FrontendAuthorize());
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}

public class FrontendAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!filterContext.Controller.GetType().Namespace.StartsWith("HSServer.Controllers.Api"))
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```